# How to enable OpenSSh on iOS 10.2

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, ssh

I have sucsessfully jailbroken my iPhone 6s runing on iOS 10.2.

I have installed OpenSSH through Cydia and changed my default password via MobileTerminal.

The only problem is, when I run `ssh root@my_iPhone_ip_addr`, it just hangs and never connects.

I have tried the SSH toggle springboard application, however it still hangs.

Is there a how I could enable SSH on my phone via a terminal command or some other way?

Comment: I use iPhone Tunnel to connect to my device via ssh over USB: https://code.google.com/archive/p/iphonetunnel-mac/downloads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[OpenSSH is not compatible with iOS 10.2 and will break things in later releases of the jailbreak.](https://twitter.com/qwertyoruiopz/status/816641319867207680) You should uninstall both OpenSSH and OpenSSL (dependency).

[yalu102 comes with dropbear.](https://twitter.com/qwertyoruiopz/status/816641460569341952)

Comment: This tweet was made prior to the 10.2 Jailbreak's release, so I'm pretty sure it's referring to the highly unstable 10.1.1 Jailbreak. Do you have an updated source?

Comment: Please follow grgarside's advice: uninstall OpenSSH. See my post for step-by-step instructions to get your ssh back.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the built-in Dropbear. As of Yalu Beta 6, you need to first SSH over USB. Then after changing your password you can enable Dropbear on other interfaces.

Linux or macOS:

1. Download gandalf binaries (I had zero luck compiling) from the [ocaml-usbmux](https://github.com/onlinemediagroup/ocaml-usbmux/releases) github page. macOS: gandalf_darwin_10_11_x86_64
2. Connect your device via USB cable, and scan for it.
3. Put the udid into a mapping file. Make sure device_port 22 (ssh) is mapped!
4. Run gandalf with your mapping file
5. SSH to the local_port corresponding to device_port 22 in your mapping file.
6. Log in with the password alpine.
7. **CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD!!!**

Scan

```
$ gandalf
```

Sample Mapping File

```
[{"udid":"9cdfac9f74c5e18a6eff3611c0927df5cf4f2eca",
  "name":"i11", "forwarding": [{"local_port":2000, "device_port":22},
                               {"local_port":3000, "device_port":1122}]
                               }]
```

Run Gandalf with Mapping File

```
$ gandalf -m myMappingFile.txt
```

SSH to port 2000

```
$ ssh mobile@localhost -p 2000
```

Change password(s)

```
$ passwd
$ su
$ passwd root
```

---

Now that you are in your iOS device (**your password has been changed, right?**) you can enable Dropbear on other interfaces as follows.

1. Create a LaunchDaemon file to launch a second instance of Dropbear.
2. Reboot or use `launchctl load`

Create LaunchDaemon file:

```
$ cd /Library/LaunchDaemons
$ cat <<EOF > ssh10022.plist
```

Paste this into the terminal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>SSH port 10022</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/dropbear</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/dropbear</string>
        <string>-F</string>
        <string>-R</string>
        <string>-p</string>
        <string>10022</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Type Ctrl-D to end the input. That now creates the file ssh10022.plist

Reboot or use launchctl

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh10022.plist
```

---

Issues:

Dropbear does not like the iOS default permissions on the mobile home directory, so SSH key authentication does not work. After every reboot I have to log in with password and fix the permissions:

```
$ chmod go-w /var/mobile
```

To debug Dropbear: Redirect Dropbear logs to stderr (the example below runs yet another instance on port 10023).

```
$ dropbear -E -p 10023
```

Answer (score 6):

You can not connect to ssh over wifi with the 10.2 jailbreak. You need to ssh over USB. They are several options but the easiest is to use `iproxy`.

1. **Install iproxy**

   `brew install libimobiledevice`
2. **On the terminal now run the following command.**

   `iproxy 2222 22`

   This will enable you to forward all traffic from port 2222 to port 22 over USB
3. **Now you can connect to the iPhone by running ssh**

   `ssh root@localhost -p 2222`

Notice you connect to `localhost` not the ip address of your phone. If everything went well, you should be presented with the ssh prompt.

If it doesnt work, check if ssh is running on the iPhone by running

`telnet <iphone-ip-address-here> 22`

If you cant connect make sure you install the `openssh` package from Cydia.

Comment: Probably shouldn't suggested installing OpenSSH because the author of the jailbreak, qwertyoruiop specifically says not to install OpenSSH.

Comment: I could not connect using `Dropbear`, in my case i had to install the `OpenSSH` package, that's the reason i suggested that as the other instructions seem to be based on the beta jailbreak

Comment: This is not true. You CAN connect on SSH over Wifi with the 10.2 Jailbreak. It just requires you to update the dropbear configuration in order to have it listen on all interfaces.

Comment: @Doug edit the answer and put the instructions on enabling SSH over wifi.

Answer (score 3):

@Colin Has a great answer for the Yulu jailbreak, but I did things a little differently that may be useful to people. His answer focuses on creating a new daemon with a new name so that effectively you have two daemons running SSH. One for the USB and one for other TCP connections. I wanted one listener that listened on all interfaces. I was also on Windows and needed something that worked with that, which Galdolf did not. As a result I went with a [Python Script](https://github.com/TestStudio/usbmuxd), which I [forked](https://github.com/securityvoid/usbmuxd) to make sure it never disappears on me.

To use this, run:

```
python usbmuxd\pythonclient\tcprelay.py -t 22:2222
```

The above maps local port 2222 to the remote port 22. Once this is setup you can use your favorite SSH utility in order to connect in. I used [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 2222

Default username of "root" and password of "alpine", but a username of "mobile" and a password of "alpine" can also be used to connect.

*NOTE: If you don't know the root password, use Filza to change the permissions of /etc/master.passwd to 666, then via SSH as the mobile user, or utilizing your favorite file editor, edit that file to copy the hash from "mobile" over to "root" to make the passwords the same. (The hash for "alpine" is "/smx7MYTQIi2M", if its needed). You then should be able to login as root then, or use su.*

Once your logged in you'll want to find the copies of droplist.plist that are currently on your machine. There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but I used the following command:

```
find . | grep dropbear.plist
```

Which yielded:

```
./Library/LaunchDaemons/dropbear.plist
./private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/023FF836-8A0A-4593-A578-6801F2A3F34D/yalu102.app/dropbear.plist
```

The first entry is the active daemon, but the second one is more important. Its the daemon that Yulu puts in place every time you run the jailbreak (Which you have to do with every reboot). If you only edit /Library/LaunchDaemons/dropbear.plist, it will be replaced every time you reboot.

As a result we're going to edit the one that comes packaged with Yulu, but if you cat the file you'll notice its in a binary PLIST format. To fix this we need  [Erica Utilities](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.ericasadun.utilities/) in order to get plutil. You can then run:

```
plutil -xml dropbear.plist
```

This will convert the dropbear.plist to XML format. Once this is done you can edit the file in any text editor. I used [nano](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/nano/) to do the actual editing.

e.g.

```
nano dropbear.plist
```

When you're editing the file you want to get rid of the "localhost:" from the last string entry. This will make the listener run on all interfaces instead of only the loopback interface (Which is only available via USB). As a result your file becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>ShaiHulud</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/dropbear</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/local/bin/dropbear</string>
                <string>-F</string>
                <string>-R</string>
                <string>-p</string>
                <string>22</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Once you've done that you will want to put the file back in binary format:

```
plutil -binary dropbear.plist
```

At this point I suggest you reboot the device and validate that the Yalu dropbear.plist file is properly copied over when you re-jailbreak:

e.g.

```
reboot
```

After a reboot you should be able to SSH utilizing your phone's IP address and the standard port 22.

e.g.

- Host: (IP From Settings -> WiFi -> (WIFI NAME)
- Port: 22

Comment: Thanks for spelling out all your steps! That makes it a lot more future-proof. I tried > find . | grep dropbear.plist to find the dropbear configuration on the LiberIOS jailbreak but I have no clue where they put the config.

Comment: Try navigating to: /Library/LaunchDaemons/ and see if you can figure out the name they used within there. Most likely they used the same name everywhere. That folder is where all the daemon scripts are, so if they have an existing daemon it will have to be referenced there.

Comment: Forgot to cd / before running find . | grep dropbear.plist. Duh.

Comment: This made me realize we could just suggest hacking the Dropbear.plist in the Yalu IPA before we upload it to the device with Impactor. But then again while one can directly edit binary .plist files with Xcode on macOS, I don’t know if such facilities exist in Windows or Linux.

Comment: Yes, it can be done: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Converting_Binary_Plists